# resultados diferentes usando rpart e caret

Tags: r, regressão

Olá,

estou testando algums modelos de regressão e não entendi bem uma coisa:
usei o rpart do pacote rpart, e depois usei o train com metodo rpart do pacote caret

```
resultRPart <- rpart(EVADIU ~ ., data = data.rose)
resultCaret <- train(EVADIU ~ ., data = data.rose, method = "rpart")
```

eu esperava que os dois dessem o mesmo resultado (precision, recall, etc) mas não é o que aconteceu

o primeiro deu

> precision : 0.599
>
> recall : 0.412

o segundo

> precision : 0.1439
>
> recall : 0.6759

isso é normal ou estou comparando laranjas com bananas aqui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `caret` por padrão faz tuning de alguns hiperparâmetros de cada modelo. Ele tenta fazer isso de uma forma inteligente, mas que nem sempre é o adequado para o seu problema. Já o `rpart` ajusta o modelo exatamente como você definiu.

O `caret` não é muito claro com isso mesmo, e as vezes gera confusão...

No caso, para o `rpart` irá tunar o hiperparâmetro `cp` (complexidade). Ele decide um *grid* para testar de acordo a a seguinte função:

```
> getModelInfo("rpart")[[1]]$grid
function (x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") 
{
    dat <- if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x
    else as.data.frame(x)
    dat$.outcome <- y
    initialFit <- rpart(.outcome ~ ., data = dat, control = rpart.control(cp = 0))$cptable
    initialFit <- initialFit[order(-initialFit[, "CP"]), , drop = FALSE]
    if (search == "grid") {
        if (nrow(initialFit) < len) {
            tuneSeq <- data.frame(cp = seq(min(initialFit[, "CP"]), 
                max(initialFit[, "CP"]), length = len))
        }
        else tuneSeq <- data.frame(cp = initialFit[1:len, "CP"])
        colnames(tuneSeq) <- "cp"
    }
    else {
        tuneSeq <- data.frame(cp = unique(sample(initialFit[, 
            "CP"], size = len, replace = TRUE)))
    }
    tuneSeq
}
```

Essa função basicamente:

- ajusta um modelo com todos os parâmetros iguais ao rpart padrão exceto o `cp`(complexidade), usando cp = 0.
- pega o item `cptable` retornado, que por definição é:

> **cptable**: a matrix of information on the optimal prunings based on a
>   complexity parameter.

- ajusta um modelo para uma sequencia de `cp`'s de acordo com o argumento `tuneLength` da função `train`.

Esse comportamento pode ser alterado. Leia aqui para mais informações: http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process